# Why this below is true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone please tell me why this is true?

$$z^m = \frac{m!}{2\pi i} \oint_C u^{m-1}e^{\frac{z}{u}}du  $$
where $C$ is contour containing point $u = 0$.

Comment: What is the residue of the function at $u=0$. Or use the generalised CIF.

Comment: I don't know that. It's just given like this, and need to know why it is true. I mean, how to prove this?

Comment: I'd try, to start, induction on $m$, by differentiation (I understand that $m$ is natural)..

Comment: Use the Residue Therorem, or use Cauchy's Intergral Formua.

Comment: Don't use induction here.

Comment: Okay, it looks like CIF, but not quite. I would appreciate it if you could send me solution. If not, thanks anyway.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Why not? I this leads to a proof, ok, if it doesn't, perhaps it enlightens about it.

Comment: Substitute $u = 1/\zeta$.

Comment: @ajotatxe, in general worth trying but here I don't think it helps until you use maxim's substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$u^{m-1}e^{z/u} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u^{m-1}\frac{(z/u)^n}{n!}.$$

Use the fact (and verify) that the integral of the above sum is the sum of the integrals. Only one of those summands will be nonzero.

Comment: I was gonna suggest to first prove by induction that if $\displaystyle f(u) = e^{\frac{z}{u}}$ then $f^{(n)} (u)= P_n\left(\frac{z}{u}\right)f(u)$ where $P_n$  is a polynomial of degree $n$; but it sounds like the same idea.